# When to use “beziehungsweise”

Tags: word-usage, meaning, difference

#### Beziehungsweise:

- a) (stilistisch unschön) *[oder] vielmehr, besser/genauer gesagt* – sinnv: oder

  > Er war mit ihm bekannt bzw. befreundet
- b) *und im anderen Fall*

  > Die Fünf- und Zweipfenningstücke waren aus Nickel bzw. [aus] Kupfer

In these examples I see how *bzw* differs from *oder* or *und* (although *beziehungsweise* wouldn’t have occured to me)

---

#### oder

but I’ve seen it used it manners that seem interchangable with *oder*

> Wie in dieser Frage festgestellt, […], diverse eingedeutschte Farbadjektive nicht zu beugen, und stattdessen Folgendes zu schreiben bzw. zu sprechen.

In this example it’s unclear to me why *bzw.* is preferable over oder

> … stattdessen Folgendes zu schreiben oder zu sprechen

---

#### Und/oder

> Die Fünf- und Zweipfenningstücke waren aus Nickel bzw. [aus] Kupfer

*Und* here would make this sentence mean “5 and 2 cent pieces were out of nickel and copper”

*Oder* here would make this sentence mean “5 and 2 cent pieces were made out of nickel of copper”

So I take the meaning to be

> Manchmal waren die Fünf- und Zweipfenningstücke aus Nickel und manchmal [aus] Kupfer
>
> (= Sometimes the 5 cent and 2 cent pieces were made of nickel and in other cases copper)

---

#### und

I’ve noticed that *bzw.* is sometimes used to mean *und* also

> Der Vorstand wurde durch Hauptversammlungsbeschluss vom 25. Januar 2007 beziehungsweise 24. Januar 2008 ermächtigt, …
>
> = By resolution of the Annual Shareholders’ Meetings on January 25, 2007 and January 24, 2008, the Managing Board was authorized …

What does *respectively* have to do with this sentence? Would *und* not work here?

---

On [German Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/beziehungsweise) it says that to use *bzw* to mean *genauer gesagt* or *oder* is *umgangssprachlich,* which only leave only *und im anderen Fall* and *und* as “correct German” but I’m still curious about the meaning and usage even if it’s non-standard.

---

I suppose the ultimate question here is: When do you use *beziehungsweise* to mean *und* or *oder*?

Comment: Sorry that the question's lengthy; just I know people have called for more documentation of prior research before asking the difference between 2+ words.

Comment: Don't apologise. This is a fantastic question.

Comment: `beziehungsweise an Sonn- und Feiertagen römisch Acht Strich 2`

Comment: I personally disagree with the "und/oder" paragraph and prefer Carsten Schultz' answer. Your assumption would be a  challenge for automatons accepting coins. According to wikipedia  5-Pfenning coins we constantly of brass-plated steel.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Cases one cannot use *und* or *oder*

**Im anderen Fall**

> Die Fünf- und Zweipfennigstücke waren aus Nickel bzw. [aus] Kupfer. (common)
> The five and two cent pieces were made out of nickel and copper *respectively.*

Here *bzw.* can be substituted by *respektive.* It **refers to the order** in which things are given.

> Die Fünf- und Zweipfennigstücke waren aus Nickel respektive Kupfer. (rarely used)

**Genauer gesagt**

> Gestern Nacht bzw. heute früh um zwei bin ich schweißgebadet aufgewacht. (common)
> Er hat sich ein Fahrrad bzw. ein Mountainbike gekauft. (common)

Here *bzw.* can be substituted e. g. by *genauer gesagt*.

> Gestern Nacht, genauer gesagt heute früh um zwei, bin ich schweißgebadet aufgewacht. (common)
> Er hat sich ein Fahrrad, genauer gesagt ein Mountainbike, gekauft. (common)

Alternatively *besser gesagt*, *das heißt*

**Synonyms**

> Die Brötchen bzw. Semmeln sind schon aus.

This case is similar to the one above. Like this one can give an alternative term.

> Die Brötchen – [oder] auch Semmeln genannt – sind schon aus.

Note that the optional *oder* is about the term and not that *either Brötchen or Semmeln* are sold out.

### Cases with *und* or *oder*

**Oder**

> … stattdessen Folgendes zu schreiben oder zu sprechen
>
> In this example it’s unclear to me why *bzw.* is preferable over *oder*.

I don’t think it is. Nevertheless it can substitute it.

**Und**

> Vergiss nicht die Autoschlüssel bzw. die Papiere (not common)

I’d say it’s possible. However, I don’t think it is used often, when things are equal. In your example it mentions *one* *Hauptversammlungsbeschluss* and therefore I guess the dates are somehow related.

Comment: Sorry, but I would never use "bzw." as in your examples (but the first), and I do not hear/read people doing it this way. It means "respecitively" and is used like the other answers explain.

Answer (score 9):

I agree that sometimes a plain „oder“ is better than „beziehungsweise“, the „schreiben bzw. sprechen“ may be an example of that.

The sentence about coins I read as:

> Die Fünfpfennigstücke waren aus Nickel, die Zweipfennigstücke waren aus Kupfer.

This is what the word „beziehungsweise“ is for. You can also say „respektive“. However, even though the coins are of different colour, this seems not to be factually correct. I hope that I was not misreading the sentence.

Regarding the last example, I imagine that after the „ermächtigt“ several points follow and that the Managing Board has been authorised regarding each of them at a particular one of the two days.

Answer (score 4):

I’d generally translate “beziehungsweise” with “respectively”.

> Die Fünf- und Zweipfenningstücke waren aus Nickel bzw. [aus] Kupfer

The relation between the first part of the sentence and the second is established by following the same order: “Die Fünfprennigstücke waren aus Nickel, die Zweipfennigstücke aus Kupfer.” This relation – “Beziehung” – to a different part of the sentence is where the word “beziehungsweise” has its root. (The accuracy of the quoted statement appears somewhat questionable, though.)

> Wie in dieser Frage festgestellt, […], diverse eingedeutschte Farbadjektive nicht zu beugen, und stattdessen Folgendes zu schreiben bzw. zu sprechen.

Here the relation is not to a different part of the sentence, but to some implicit context. If you are writing, then you should write as follows. If you are speaking, then you should speak as follows. So you should be writing respectively speaking as follows.

> Der Vorstand wurde durch Hauptversammlungsbeschluss vom 25. Januar 2007 beziehungsweise 24. Januar 2008 ermächtigt, …

I assume that the subsequent text will mention (directly or indirectly) several distinct powers given to the Board. If it’s exactly two, the first would have been granted 2007, the second 2008. If there is more than two then the attribution is less clear. Looking at [the likely source of this citation](http://www.siemens.com/investor/pool/de/investor_relations/d08_00_gb2008.pdf), it seems that there are four distinct powers following that introduction.

> Er war mit ihm bekannt bzw. befreundet

This I’d indeed consider pretty bad style. There is no evident relation here, so I’d not know what the word could supposedly be referring to. I’d assume the speaker would be using the word without actually knowing its correct use. “Besser” or “genauer gesagt” would indeed be more appropriate choices here.

Comment: Siehe [diese Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/24804/15318) zum Anführungszeichenthema ;)