# Anführungszeichen bei fremdsprachigen Zitaten

Tags: typography, quotes

Wenn man in einem deutschen Text eine englische Phrase zitiert, und diese in Anführungszeichen setzt, sind dann deutsche oder englische Anführungszeichen zu verwenden? Für deutsche Zitate in englischen Texten gilt sinngemäß dieselbe Frage.

Anders formuliert: Sind die Anführungszeichen Teil des Zitates das sie umschließen, oder Teil des umgebenden Textes?

Welche dieser Varianten ist richtig, welche ist falsch:

> 1. Hans behauptete, dass “to be or not to be” das bekannteste Shakespeare-Zitat sei.
> 2. Hans behauptete, dass „to be or not to be“ das bekannteste Shakespeare-Zitat sei.
> 3. Hans behauptete, dass »to be or not to be« das bekannteste Shakespeare-Zitat sei.

Und umgekehrt dieselbe Frage:

> 1. James didn't understand the meaning of “durch diese hohle Gasse muss er kommen”.
> 2. James didn't understand the meaning of „durch diese hohle Gasse muss er kommen“.
> 3. James didn't understand the meaning of »durch diese hohle Gasse muss er kommen«.

Damit es noch klarer wird, noch ein deutsch-japanisches Beispiel (die japanischen Anführungszeichen sind 「 und 」. Der zitierte japanische Satz lautet auf deutsch: »Tschüß bis zum nächsten Sommer«):

> 1. Kyoko verabschiedete sich mit den Worten: 「来夏までバイバイ」.
> 2. Kyoko verabschiedete sich mit den Worten: „来夏までバイバイ“.
> 3. Kyoko verabschiedete sich mit den Worten: »来夏までバイバイ«.

---

Der folgende Teil ist nicht mehr Teil der Frage, sondern dient nur zur Klarstellung, welche Anführungszeichen in welcher Sprache üblich sind:

**American English:**

> Maria said to her son: “Didn't your dad already say ‘no’?”

Äußere Anführungszeichen:
Öffnend: oben, das Zeichen erinnern in seiner Form an die Zahl *66*.
Schließend: oben, sieht wie *99* aus.

Innere Anführungszeichen (Zitat im Zitat): Gleich wie die äußeren Zeichen, aber in einfacher Ausführung (oben 6 – oben 9)

Alternativ findet man in amerikanischen Texten auch die britische Version.

**British English:**

> Maria said to her son: ‘Didn't your dad already say “no”?’

Doppelt und einfach werden genau umgekehrt wie im amerikanischen Englisch verwendet. Alternativ findet man in britischen Texten auch die amerikanische Version.

**Deutsch:**

> Maria sagte zu ihrem Sohn: „Hat dein Vater nicht bereits ‚nein‘ gesagt?“

Außen: unten *99* – oben *66*.
Innen: unten *9* – oben *6*.

**Deutsche Alternative (überall wo deutsch gesprochen wird, außer in der Schweiz)**

> Maria sagte zu ihrem Sohn: »Hat dein Vater nicht bereits ›nein‹ gesagt?«

Äußeres Zitat: Zwei Spitzen auf Höhe der Mitte der Kleinbuchstaben zeigen nach innen.
Inneres Zitat: Eine Spitze zeigt nach innen.
In der hier verwendeten Form heißen diese Zeichen *Chevrons*.

**zweite Deutsche Alternative (nur in der Schweiz)**

> Maria sagte zu ihrem Sohn: «Hat dein Vater nicht bereits ‹nein› gesagt?»

Wie oben, aber die Spitzen zeigen nach außen. Die Zeichen sind dieselben wie in der nicht-schweizerischen Variante, heißen jetzt aber *Guillemets*.

Comment: Das japanische Beispiel wirft noch ein weiteres Problem auf: Es ist nicht unwahrscheinlich, dass dieses Zitat transliteriert würde - und dann stünden die japansichen Anführungszeihen gar nicht mehr zur Verfügung: Kyoko verabschiedete sich mit den Worten: "honda kawasaki" (Sorry, I have no idea *at  all* how to transliterate japanese)

Comment: Die Möwchen (noch ein Name für » und «, analog zu »Gänsefüßchen«) mit der Spitze nach außen findet man manchmal auch bei Texten aus Deutschland. Ich glaube die Hausregeln bei Rowohlt Verlag schreiben die vor.

Comment: @ospalh: Tatsächlich! Die Anführungszeichen auf der Webseite von Rowolt sind falsch herum gesetzt. Das habe ich auch den Aussendungen des Wiener Konzerthauses gesehen. Auf meine Nachfrage hin (ich singe ja häufig dort) teilte man mir aber mit, dass das aus Unwissenheit geschah. In den darauffolgenden Aussendungen setzte man diese Zeichen dann wie in Österreich (und Deutschland) üblich. Aber generell sind solche Regeln (wie auch alle Rechtschreib- und Grammatik-Regeln) ja nichts weiter als unverbindliche Empfehlungen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Feste Regeln gibt es diesbezüglich meines Wissens nicht, also wirst Du bestenfalls wohlbegründete Meinungen finden. Hier ist meine:

> Sind die Anführungszeichen Teil des Zitates das sie umschließen, oder Teil des umgebenden Textes?

Semantisch gehören die Anführungszeichen ganz klar zum umgebenen Text, da sie in diesem anzeigen, dass das Angeführte auf einer anderen inhaltlichen Ebene steht. Im wiedergegebenen Text tauchen Anführungszeichen nicht auf, sondern werden erst durch die Wiedergabe nötig. Gerade im Fremdsprachenbeispiel wird dies dadurch deutlich, dass ich auch etwas in Anführungszeichen kann, das gar keiner Sprache zuordenbar ist, z. B.:

> If he was dying, he wouldn’t bother to carve “Aaargh”.
>
> An die Wand stand mit weißer Farbe »AXXᵒN N.« geschrieben.
>
> »Gift« bedeutet im Deutschen etwas anderes als im Englischen.

Typografisch würde ich mich an den Gewohnheiten des Lesers orientieren, die durch den umgebenden Text und nicht durch das Angeführte bestimmt sind. Letzteres kennt der Leser ja noch gar nicht, wenn er über das erste Anführungszeichen stolpert.

Außerdem kann das Nutzen der Anführungszeichen der Sprache des Angeführten unübersichtlich oder zumindest hässlich werden, wenn aus mehreren Sprachen in kurzer Folge angeführt wird (wobei ich in so einem Fall sowieso eine andere Auszeichnung, z. B. Kursivierung, bevorzugen würde):

> « idée fixe », »fixe Idee« und “idée fixe“ bezeichnen alle das gleiche.

Schließlich gibt es noch das Problem, dass Du aus einer Sprache zitieren möchtest, die gar keine Anführungszeichen im heutigen Sinne genutzt hat, z. B. Altgriechisch oder Latein (zumindest konnte ich auf die Schnelle nichts Gegenteiliges finden).

Aus all diesen Gründen würde ich Anführungszeichen im Fließtext auf jeden Fall an der Sprache des umschließenden Textes orientieren.

Answer (score 4):

Die typografische Regel lautet, dass man fremdsprachige Zitate in den Anführungszeichen der fremden Sprache setzen sollte.

Die im *Duden* angegebenen Hinweise für die Textverarbeitung schränken diese Regel jedoch etwas ein. Demnach werden bei ganzen Sätzen oder Absätzen aus fremden Sprachen die in dieser Sprache üblichen Anführungszeichen verwendet. Bei einzelnen aus fremden Sprachen angeführten Wörtern und Wendungen werden dagegen die Anführungszeichen wie im deutschen Text gesetzt.

Comment: Ich habe meiner Frage nachträglich ein deutsch-japanisches Beispiel hinzugefügt, weil die japanischen Anführungszeichen ganz anders aussehen als die deutschen oder englischen. Da wird es schwierig, diese Zeichen überhaupt als Anführungszeichen zu erkennen, aber laut deiner Antwort sind sie zu verwenden, weil der zitierte Inhalt ein ganzer Satz ist. Hier die japanischen Zeichen zu verwendet kommt mir seltsam vor.

Comment: Ich hätte grundsätzlich deutsche Interpunktion in einem deutschen Text benutzt. Wenn man das jedoch anders sieht, sehe ich nicht so ganz, wieso japanische Anführungszeichen problematisch sein sollten: jemand der Kanji oder Hiragana/Katakana lesen kann, wird sie verstehen, und die anderen verstehen eh nichts :)

Comment: *Die typografische Regel lautet, dass man fremdsprachige Zitate in den Anführungszeichen der fremden Sprache setzen sollte.* – Wer sagt das? Ich bezweifle, dass hierüber unter Typographen Einigkeit herrscht.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Das steht z. B. in _Detailtypografie_ von Forssman und de Jong. Ich habe bislang nirgendwo Gegenteiliges gelesen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Die japanischen Anführungszeichen sehen vor allem für die seltsam aus, die kein Japanisch lesen können. Wer dein Zitat lesen kann, kennt wahrscheinlich auch die Anführungszeichen. Wenn man das Zitat transkribiert würde ich deutsche Anführungszeichen nehmen: »Kyoko verabschiedete sich mit den Worten: ›Raika made bai-bai‹«.

Comment: @Loong hast Du ein Zitat und/oder ein Beispiel aus *Detailtypografie*? Die Regel erscheint mit semantisch nämlich reichlich unlogisch. (Etwas anderes ist es, wenn *innerhalb* eines Zitates Anführungszeichen auftauchen.)

Comment: @cgnieder Die genannte Regel steht fast genau so in der _Detailtypografie_. Darauf folgt ein extremes Beispiel mit drei unterschiedlichen Anführungen in einem Satz: « C’est la vie » kann man so setzen und gleich danach “last, but not least” so, aber es sieht doch aufdringlich nach »Musterbuch« aus. Dazu wird erklärt, warum man für dieses Beispiel die Regel ignorieren darf, was jedoch weniger mit Huberts Frage zu tun hat. – Du hast Recht, dass _innerhalb_ von fremdsprachigen Zitaten auf jeden Fall die zur jeweiligen Sprache gehörigen Anführungszeichen verwendet werden.

Comment: @Loong Interessant. Geben sie eine Begründung, warum man nicht die Zeichen der umgebenden Sprache verwenden soll? Unterschiedliche Zeichen widersprechen IMHO eigentlich der Regel Nummer eins (Konsistenz).