# How to say "respectively" in German when listing (enumerating) things

Tags: translation, english-to-german

In English and many other languages I could say something like this:

> Tom and Jack play football and baseball respectively.

That means that Tom plays football and Jack plays baseball.

How can I say this in German? What is the equivalent of "respectively"?

Comment: What did your dictionary suggest?

Comment: recht and passend, but I don't think, that these are correct, because I could not find any sentence with these used in the context I am looking for here.

Comment: @matvs would you please edit your post and add were you've looked it up and what you've found?

Comment: I would add that if 'respectively' is used to mean 'each' then this would be expressed by 'je' in German.

Comment: "Tom spielt Fußball und Jack spielt Baseball". :D

Comment: @matvs: could you please edit your question to include your findings? (and why you think they are nonfitting)

Comment: This doesn't sound idiomatic at all.

Comment: I also feel like "Tom spielt Fußball während Jack Baseball spielt" is the closest to the meaning while still having an authentic sentence. "Respektive" and "beziehungsweise" sound a bit too hard trying to me.

Answer (score 52):

This is expressed with the conjunction [*beziehungsweise*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/beziehungsweise) (often abbreviated *bzw.*) in the meaning *und im andern Fall* (in the other case).

Admittedly, the structure of a German sentence containing *beziehungsweise* is different from the structure of an English sentence containing *and ... respectively*. Rather than translating word by word, one replaces the conjunction *and* by the conjunction *beziehungsweise*. The adverb *respectively* is dropped, because it is already implicit in the conjunction *beziehungsweise*. For example, the sentence

> Tom and Jack play football *and* baseball, *respectively*.

is translated to

> Tom und Jack spielen Fußball *beziehungsweise* Baseball.

meaning that Tom plays football and Jack plays baseball.

Comment: The "beziehungsweise" gives the example sentence a bit of a technical / bureaucratic / wooden vibe. To phrase it like it this in German is significantly less natural or common than the English counterpart with "respectively". To prevent misunderstandings, a German native speaker would probably rather make two sentences: "Tom spielt Fußball, und Jack (spielt) Baseball."

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck  That's right. But isn't the English "respectively" also a bit bureaucratic? I have never heared somebody using it in causal speech, or in an everyday situation. I think both *beziehungsweise* and *respectively* are expressions to emphasize the separateness of notions, and such kind of over-precision is not usual nor necessary in everyday communication.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I'm not an English native speaker, but from my experience "respectively" is more commonly used than "beziehungsweise". For example, it's not that uncommon to find "respectively" used like in this question in a newspaper article or a podcast. Or maybe I'm reading the wrong newspapers ;)

Comment: This answer is not correct as it doesn't work with an ambiguous object. As duden mentions it works on things that can clearly not be true for both subjects like `ihre Tochter und ihr Sohn sind sechs beziehungsweise acht Jahre alt` (her daughter and son are six and eight respectively). But this answers example could as well mean that Tom AND Jack play soccer AND baseball.
I'm a native speaker.

Comment: It's worth noting that "bzw" is much more versatile than "respectively". Often the best translation of "bzw" into English is "and/or". Part of the problem is that "bzw" in German is often used casually and (according to the pedants) incorrectly; another part is that "bzw" is a conjunction while "respectively" is an adverb. If you see the sentence "Use this cable to connect your printer respectively your scanner", you know it's written by a German. But for this example, the equivalence works.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck I disagree with you here. I see "bzw" used much more informally, and with a much less precise meaning, than "respectively". When you see "respectively" in English, it's generally written either (a) by someone thinking very precisely, like a lawyer or mathematician, or (b) by someone mistranslating from German.

Comment: @steros: "But this answers example could as well mean that Tom AND Jack play soccer AND baseball." - how do you come to that conclusion? IMHO, it *cannot* mean that precisely because of the "beziehungsweise". Were the example just "Tom und Jack spielen Fußball und Baseball.", it would indeed be ambiguous the way you describe.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Yes it can because `beziehungsweise` can also mean `oder (or)`. You can compare with Duden. And in common speech it would almost be understood as `und (and)` (in this example). This is because the objects are ambiguous in relation to the subject. Both subjects could play both. Rather than two people having two ages. The problem is that in this case, at least I can't think of something, you can't simply use one word to make the statement more precise. You need a different pattern to be precise.

Comment: I would say generally steros is right that beziehungsweise is not equivalent to respectively especially for this reason. And the sentence built in the answer is not what I would use as a native speaker at all exactly for that reason. Still I would rather it interpret it, the way it was intended still it is not the only possible interpretation. 'respektive' is just the better fit here.

Comment: bezuehungsweise ist sicher kein und/oder. "Tom und Jack spielen Fußball beziehungsweise Baseball." heißt entweder "Tom spielt Fußball und Jack spielt Baseball." oder, theoretisch, "Tom und Jack spielen beide entweder Fußball oder Baseball, je nach Umständen."

Comment: Related - [When to use “beziehungsweise”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9894/when-to-use-beziehungsweise)

Comment: @ths please proof your statement

Comment: It's important to point out that *beziehungsweise* is more often seen by its abbreviation *bzw.*

Comment: Couldn't it mean that Tom & Jack are playing right now, either soccer or baseball?

Comment: For what it's worth, I just asked 3 native German speakers and none of them thought that this translation is clear or makes much sense at all.

Comment: @EricDuminil when you mean “playing right now, either soccer or baseball” you’d use just “oder”. The translation in this answer is as close as you can get, for a construct that you normally wouldn’t use at all. In German, you simply wouldn’t merge the two entirely independent facts, “Tom plays football” and “Jack plays baseball” into a single sentence (besides concatenating the sentences with “und” or a comma). There are other cases, where translating “respectively” with “beziehungsweise” works much better, i.e. when merging the facts into a single statement is justified.

Comment: @Holger: Thanks a lot. It means that this answer could be updated to mention that this structure isn't typically used in German, and that "Tom spielt Fußball und Jack spielt Baseball" would be easier and clearer.

Comment: Die Antwort ist korrekt; allerdings ist das Original blödsinnig; das macht eine wirklich gute Übersetzung etwas schwierig.

Comment: @TaW the original sentence is fine and unambiguous, but probably shouldn't be translated to German as is.

Answer (score 19):

Ich pflichte Björn Friedrich bei, dass

> Tom und Jack spielen Fußball beziehungsweise Baseball.

die vorherrschende Form ist, derartiges auf Deutsch auszudrücken, möchte aber ergänzen, dass

> Tom und Jack spielen Fußball, respektive Baseball.

auch nicht ganz ungebräuchlich ist, aber im Straßenjargon ist es sehr selten.

Comment: Die Frage ist ein Duplikat und nicht das erste. Ich sah einst die Empfehlung "X bzw. Y spielen A bzw B" zu schreiben. Das leuchtet ein, der Reim ist Fett, wie die Beginner einst sagten. Sagen würden das wenige, ich hab es mir zwar angewöhnt, denke eher "Tom spielt Fußball, Jack Basketball"

Comment: Kommt mir altmodisch vor, vor Allem wenn ich da meinen Opa höre, der "reschpektive" gesagt hat...

Comment: @ths: Zwar kommt es mir auch vor, als hätte ich es vor 10-20 Jahren häufiger gehört (und benutzt) als heute, aber dennoch fällt es mir schwer, etwas was erst 30 Jahre her ist als altmodisch zu bezeichnen - k.A. wie alt Du bist. Altmodisch ist für mich 50er und früher. Ich selbst bin vielleicht alt, aber doch nicht altmodisch. :)

Answer (score 10):

**Baseline**

While `respectively` typically translates to `beziehungsweise`, `respektive` or `jeweils`, neither seems optimal in your example. As @steros has pointed out in a comment, the translation ...

> Tom und Jack spielen Fußball, respektive / beziehungsweise Baseball.

... suffers from a subject ambiguity that produces a reading in which *both* boys would play *both* sports. Pragmatics might filter this reading in the given example (for 'beziehungsweise' would suggest that both sports were related in some way, possibly to the extent that the latter were a specialization of the former, so since the relationship here is tenuous, the translation would probably work as intended). However, the preferred reading is much less pronounced if the sentence comes with very disparate leisure activities:

> Tom und Jack spielen Fußball beziehungsweise Schach.
>   [Tom and Jack play football and chess, respectively.]

Note that the problem does not arise in a context that implies an ordering, as in

> Tom und Jack wurden Dritter beziehungsweise Vierter.
>   [Tom and Jack ranked third and fourth, respectively.]

as different ranks cannot be held simultaneously.

**Improvement**

A better translation would be:

> Tom spielt Fußball, respektive Jack Baseball.

which resolves any ambiguity though it still feels a bit odd - you'd rather express the contrast with a conjunction:

> Tom spielt Fußball, Jack hingegen Baseball. / Während Tom Fußball spielt, spielt Jack Baseball.
>   [Tom plays football while Jack plays baseball]

**Caveat**

All grammaticality assessments based on native-speaker intuition, no formal references.

Comment: I'm not sure, but what's wrong with `jeweils`? Tom und Jack spielen jeweils Fußball und Baseball. Although to be honest, I'd just say "Tom spielt Fußball und Jack spielt Baseball" without any extra complications.

Comment: @m01 The semantics of `jeweils` include a meaning that partitions time into periods where exactly one of the given alternatives happen, ie. football and baseball being played, respectively ( scnr ;) ), by both boys. There also is the meaning that each of the boys plays football and baseball. To me that is the dominant reading right now, though it might be that I've become biased by considering the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It is a common mistake when translations attempt to preserve the syntax of the source language. The correct question in the context of translation is not how one might translate the English construction `X and Y do A and B respectively` into German, but **what a native speaker of German would say** when they want to convey the same meaning. And what a native speaker of German would say is:

## Tom spielt Fußball, und Jack spielt Baseball.

Comment: do you have any objections to "Tom und Jack spielen Fußball beziehungsweise Baseball"?

Comment: @JohnHennig that’s not the point. The point of the answer is what a native speaker would *not* say, i.e. “beziehungsweise” or “respektive”.

Comment: `Tom spielt Fußball und Jack spielt Baseball` is grammatically correct but would be considered poor style due to the doubling of the verb and of the sentence structure. In fact I've rarely run into communication by a native speaker that would not apply elision (whether orally or in writing): `Tom spielt Fußball und Jack Baseball`.

Comment: @userunknown Bitte entferne nicht das Komma, es ist hier korrekt (auch wenn es nicht mehr notwendig ist).

Comment: @JohnHennig A wife gives her logical husband instructions for a trip to the grocer. The wife asks, Can you pick up a carton of milk? And if they have eggs, get six. Upon returning, the wife finds that the husband has bought six cartons of milk. And she asks, Why did you get six cartons of milk? The husband answers, Because they had eggs.

Comment: @SnotBubble: Nach welcher Regel ist das Komma richtig?

Comment: @userunknown Duden: "Bei gereihten Hauptsätzen, die mit und/oder verbunden sind, darf ein Komma gesetzt werden". Im Duden ist das die Regel Nr. 119, dort 2. Absatz: https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma#D119 Beispiel des Duden: Anna liest die Zeitung[,] und Otto löst ein Kreuzworträtsel.

Comment: This answere is correct. Most german ppl. would not get the meaning of "respectivly", because it is unusual to say things in this way. A native speaker would definitv say it like this

Answer (score 1):

The weakness of a sentence like

> Tom und Jack spielen Fußball, respektive / beziehungsweise Baseball.

is that it is not clear if it relates to "Tom and Jack respectively", or any other entity mentioned before. "Beziehungsweise" also means in german "more precisely" or "rather". I wouldn't use it in that way.

Answer (score 1):

Although the answers of Björn Friedrich and user unknown are correct in giving good translations of *respectively*, it is not really common to use this construction to express two relations, especially if it contains potential ambiguity. The natural way to express this situation in German would be to completely let go the concept of *respectively* and use two connected main clauses.
In German, if you want to prevent the sentence from becoming too long and/or complicated, it is quite common to omit some words or parts of words that are not essential for understanding, so if Tom plays A and Jack plays B you omit the second "plays". Also most of the time "Fußball und Baseball" would be shortened to "Fuß- und Baseball".
So the **most idiomatic** translation of your sentence into German would be to abandon *respectively* and say:

> Tom spielt Fuß- und Jack Baseball.

Answer (score -3):

What about this version ?

> Tom und Jack spielen entsprechend Fußball und Baseball
>
> Mein Sohn und meine Tochter sind entsprechend sechs und acht Jahre alt

Comment: I'd say that `entsprechend` cannot be used to disambiguate subject-object relationships. Rather it refers to a constituent outside the scope of the sentence proper, often establishing a causal relationship. Example: `Hamburg ist eine Hochburg des Ballsports. Tom und Jack spielen entsprechend Fußball und Baseball. [Hamburg is a stronghold of ball sports. Tom and Jack play football and baseball accordingly]`, meaning that Tom _and_ Jack do _both_ sports).

Comment: Die richtige Lösung ist hier: ***Tom und Jack spielen beide Fußball und Baseball.***

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I beg to disagree: To me *beide* indicates that "both", i.e. *each of them*, plays football *and* baseball. That is, "beide" shifts the meaning in the wrong direction.

Comment: @julodnik "Entsprechend" would refer to something said before, like "Meine Jungs mögen Sport viel lieber als Lesen. Tom und Jack spielen **entsprechend** Fußball und Baseball, während die Mädels Dauerkunden in der Bibliothek sind."

Answer (score -3):

The most common construction using "beziehungsweise" is explained in other answers.  If you care for a similar sentence hierarchy to the English version, you can use

> Tom und Jack spielen jeweils American Football und Baseball.

As a note aside: where "baseball" rather than "cricket" is a thing, "football" does not mean "soccer" and thus cannot be translated as "Fußball".

Comment: In my book the "jeweils" indicates that *each* of the two plays *both* games.

Comment: Like "Die Spieler brauchen **jeweils** ein Paar Fußballschuhe, Hose und Trikot." The statement applies *je Person* / per person. Admittedly the example is much less ambiguous as far as the subject matter is concerned ;-).